# How to learn reading complex math formulas?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, formulas

I am a programmer, but when I am faced complex mathematical formulas I am often stuck.

Please suggest a good video lecture resource that teaches reading math symbols, quantifiers etc.

Comment: First of all, for programmer math is the tool. this relation is not vice -versa ! i wonder how you do programming of algorithms without grasp of math.

Comment: There is a difference between knowledge of algorithms and ability to read the above expressions.

Comment: At least we agree that formulas are related to code. Good. Let me ask my question again then: Being a programmer, how do you learn to read this?

Comment: It doesn't matter how complex the equation is. You still have to decompose problem to smaller ones. It's just a little bit more work

Comment: @Lex by going to school. If You are lacking math knowledge just grab a precalculus book.

Comment: Very well, we have established that my higher math needs work. Let's all laugh and move on. So far none of you offered anything useful.

Comment: Huu, nobody mentioned FORTRAN?? FORmula TRANslation...

Comment: @Lex unfortunately, to understand mathematical formulas you need to learn math. Just like to understand source code you need to learn to program. But if you're asking about this particular formula, then you just need to know that sigma means summation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma and the reverse `d`s are partial derivatives http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative ; and the `p` in the formula may be the derivation order, or an index to a vector, tensor, matrix.

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk Sure thing, that's what I am trying to do. I am just trying to see if there is a good source to learn math in a programmer-friendly way. For example you said: sigma is summation, that's a good start. Now I'd like to read an article explaining how summation/sigma can be expressed in programming language.

Comment: There is no generic translation from an arbitrary mathematical entity into an algorithm. There is a number of limited, not perfect, tricky numeric methods one can employ for solving certain calculus problems, there are several heuristics for algoritmisation of a certain narrow class of the logical problems, but all this stuff is a huge, complicated scientific discipline which requires a rigorous learning. There are no easy ways. For most of the mathematical problems there are no algorithmic solutions at all.

Comment: P.S., if you want to learn math in a "programmer-friendly" way, try reading Coq, Maxima and Axiom sources, they contain a good amount of mathematical knowledge perfectly formalised. But do not expect to find "algorithms" and other equally trivial and boring stuff there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula means nothing without a context. It seems to be the derivation of the partial derivative of E<sup>p</sup> with respect to y<sub>h</sub><sup>p</sup>, which turns out to be the negative of the sum of products of δ<sub>o</sub><sup>p</sup> and w<sub>po</sub>, with o ranging from 1 to N<sub>o</sub>:

```
def partial_of_E_wrt_y(p):
    acc = 0
    for o in range(1, No):
        acc = acc + delta[p][o] * w[p][o]
    return -acc
```

E, y and δ may be [tensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) because of the use of superscript indexes. This would also means that δ<sub>o</sub><sup>p</sup>w<sub>po</sub> could be a tensor product. Or it could be that the author simply likes using superscript indexes without any association with tensors, a convention I have seen in some texts on machine learning. If δ has not been given any other interpretation, it's possible it stands for the [Kronecker delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), which would mean δ<sub>o</sub><sup>p</sup> = 1 if o=p, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to decipher this. I gave this formula only as an example of the kind of things I'd like to learn to understand, not the translation. I am looking for a good tutorial if you know it. Thank you.

Comment: A tutorial for mathematical notation? Try looking at notes from an intro level university course, or see a long list of symbols with their meanings here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols (some common, some specific particular fields)